# Align button to the bottom

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use a form, label is displayed over input.
How to align the button, to the button?

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <label for="searchLodgerNumber">Numéro</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Numéro, 2 caractère" name="searchLodgerNumber" id="searchLodgerNumber">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <label for="searchLodgerLastName">Nom</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nom, min 2 caractère" name="searchLodgerLastName" id="searchLodgerLastName">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button id="lodgerSearch" type="button"  class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
    </div>
  </form>
</form>
```

I Created a demo here

Just check of the modified Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/6wavvbxx/1/

[image]

Edit

I search to get[image]

Comment: you mean put the search button below?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,  I re-structured the HTML classes a bit with the button:

Fiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6wavvbxx/5/)

```
  <div class="col-xs-1">
     <div class="spacer"></div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
     </button>
  </div>
```

Custom CSS:

```
.spacer{
  margin-bottom:23px;
}
```

Comment: did you view the Fiddle ? it looks fine there

Comment: The same code above applies, but try placing the button in its own Form-group class. Try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6wavvbxx/8/

Comment: Gotcha, you want to align the button to the `right` not the bottom. Give me a few mins.

Comment: I created a custom css class called `spacer` and added it above the button, to compensate for the label's text height. View fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6wavvbxx/9/ (You can modify CSS as you please)